# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined and const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;

Tags: json, visual-studio, android-studio

VisualSTd shows me since today this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined".

To be more specific, it's telling me " const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;"
^
I'm new to Jason and I don't know it very well.What I've written here wrong,that I get this error again and again.Unfortunately I don't know what I can change.

```
'use strict'

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();




exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  const original = req.query.text;

  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});

  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});

});

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

      const original = snap.data().original;

      functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
      
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
  
    });






 const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
 const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;

 const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service : 'gmail',
    auth : {
        user : gmailEmail,
        pass : gmailPassword,
    },
 });



 const APP_NAME = 'InstaCloneMm'

 exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)  => {           
        const email = user.email;
        const displayName = user.displayName;

    return this.sendWelcomeEmail(email , displayName);
 });


 async function sendWelcomeEmail(email , displayName)  {            
     const mailOptions = {
         from : `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com`,
         to : email,
     };

     mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;               
        mailOptions.text = `Hey ${diasplayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}, we hope you enjoy our service.`;        


        await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log('New email sent to:' , email);             


        return null;

       
 }
```

Comment: Did you solve this?? I have the same issue